# Use string to call a variable

Tags: javascript

I know this seems bad practice, but it's for a quick and dirty class project.

Essentially, I want to store a string and use the string to call an array.

For example, if I have my data structured like this:

```
var test = {   top_level_01: 
                  {    second_level_01: [2, 3, 4],
                       second_level_02: [5, 6, 7]
                  },
               top_level_02:
                  {    second_level_03: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                       second_level_04: ['d', 'e', 'f']
                  }
           }
```

I want the string to initialize at 'top_level_01'. But at some point, I may want to see the second_level_01. So I want the string to be 'top_level_01' + "second_level_01". Then I want to call that string and return the values of [2, 3, 4].

Is this possible? Once again, I know it's bad practice, but this is just a quick proof of concept for a class project.

Comment: Are you going to add some sort of separator?

Comment: You already can; it's one way object access already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the object properties on deeper levels, as you have it. You cant just use string as "top_level_01" + "second_level_01" because the result would be "top_level_01second_level_01", which in case you don't have any specified format of each level does not carry any information about what object you are referring to. I guess the most easy way to solve this is to use a dot notation. So instead the first case you will have "top_level_01.second_level_01", so the dot will separate the levels. You can use whatever char you want instead of the dot, just remember you can't use it in the key names.

This piece of code takes use of the dot notation. I added a function "test.at()" which takes your string as argument and return object reference of the object you want.

```
            var test = {

                top_level_01 : {
                    second_level_01: [2, 3, 4],
                    second_level_02: [5, 6, 7]
                },

                top_level_02 : {
                    second_level_03: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    second_level_04: ['d', 'e', 'f']
                },

                at : function( str ) {
                    if ( ~str.indexOf('.') ) {
                        var keys = str.split('.'),
                            ref = this[ keys[0] ];

                        for ( var i = 1; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
                            ref = ref[ keys[i] ];
                        }

                        return ref;

                    } else {
                        return this[ str ];
                    }

                }
            }

            var str = 'top_level_02.second_level_03'

            test.at( str ); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried this and it works just as I need to! Sorry, I did forget the '.'. It's no problem to append that in the process.

Answer (score 3):

You can access your object with strings by using bracket notation, and it's not even bad pratice to do so :

```
var str1 = 'top_level_01',
    str2 = 'second_level_01';

var result = test[str1][str2]; // == [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This isn't quite what I was looking for. But you did manage to give me an idea about how to approach this.